# Firebase hosting with a custom domain name still uses 'xxx.firebaseapp.com'

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have followed all the instructions to add my custom domain name to my Firebase app.

I now have 3 domains.

1. The firebaseapp.com domain is flagged as Default (there is no way to change this setting) or delete this domain
2. example.com - is connected
3. www.example.com redirects to example.com.

That is all fine, except when you type in the firebaseapp.com address- it shows my website content. If that address cannot be deleted, then I need it to redirect to example.com.

I saw other posts that recommend adding:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
```

I have tried this but it makes no difference.

How do I get rid of the firebaseapp.com domain from my website, or redirect it to my domain name?

Comment: Note: for others who are creeped out by firebase app insisting on displaying code on a firebase domain, you need to file feature requests. It takes peer pressure to get google to fix problems. They won't give information about whether requests will be actioned. They need to see numbers to take notice. FR link is in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Hosting will always serve content from the shared domain, there is presently no way to disable it. The `<link rel="canonical">` suggestions will prevent search engines and crawlers from indexing the content on the shared domain.

I'd recommend filing a [feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=/report/features) if you'd like to see different functionality there.

Comment: why would anyone want a firebase app address to serve private content? Firebase is definitely a short term solution if this can't be disabled